# Finding number of existance of elements of a list in another all inclusive list

Tags: python, list

I would like to perform the following action without for loops.

```
[[elem2.count(elem1) for elem1 in list1] for elem2 in list2]
```

here, list2 is a list of lists which contain elements of type that is the same with element type of list1.

Example:

```
list1 = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4'] 
list2 = [['word1', 'word3', 'word1'], ['word2', 'word1', 'word2', 'word4', 'word4', 'word4']]
```

The result should be:

```
[[2, 0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]]
```

When the lists are huge, the nested for loops take an unnecessarily long time to complete. Hence, looking for a faster solution.

Comment: Please give example of what the two lists look like.

Comment: I have no idea what your data structure looks like. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why/how your current solution is lacking and why you'd prefer to avoid `for` loops.

Comment: I have added an example. Basically list1 looks like a list of dictionary elements, and list2 is a list of articles.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your current solution takes long on large lists is that it's O(n**2).  But you can do it in O(n) if you just build a counter in one pass, then work with that.

The `for` loop is not the enemy, it's just a question of your algorithmic complexity.

```
from collections import Counter

counters = [Counter(li) for li in list2]

[[cnt[x] for x in list1] for cnt in counters]
Out[9]: [[2, 0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]]
```

Comment: But if you're really averse to the list comprehensions you can write it `map(lambda c:map(c.__getitem__, list1), map(Counter, list2))`

Comment: @user3525820 please be more specific. What results does it give? It appears to give correct results given your example and stated desired output.

Comment: The counter is created over the characters of list1, not the words. The first part should be:   counters = [Counter(li.split()) for li in list2]. But I am trying to figure out the rest.

Comment: All I can say to that is that either your real data does not match your example data, or you've transcribed the code I provided incorrectly.

Comment: @roippi Here is the resulting counters from your code, which is obviously wrong:

[Counter({'d': 2, 'o': 2, 'r': 2, 'w': 2, ' ': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1}), Counter({'d': 4, 'o': 4, 'r': 4, 'w': 4, ' ': 3, '1': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '2': 1})]
[Counter({'t': 2, '1': 1, ' ': 1, 's': 1, 'e': 1}), Counter({'e': 4, 't': 4, ' ': 3, 'c': 2, 's': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'l': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'r': 1})]

Comment: You did `counters = [Counter(li) for li in list1]` instead of `counters = [Counter(li) for li in list2]`.  You build the counters against the SECOND list.  Just like in the code I posted.